# 2D lists Not indexing correctly

Tags: python, arrays, list, nested, 2d

I have the following simple 2D lists program:

```
rowMatrix = [0]*4
matrix = [rowMatrix]*4

for a in range(4):
    for b in range(4):
        matrix[a][b] = random.randrange(0,2)
print(matrix)`
```

It seems like it would put random numbers (0, 1) in all 16 cells of the 4x4 array. But all 4 rows are identical every time. What's wrong?

Comment: See [How do I create a multidimensional list](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list) in the official FAQ.

Comment: This is a dup of about 300 other questions. I've linked one of them, but a quick search, or just scanning through the "Related" links, should turn up the rest.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil: If you have enough rep, please vote to close the question as a dup, instead of just adding a comment.

Comment: I flagged it before adding the comment. The flag suggested a question which was also a duplicate. I can't cast a close vote as yet.

Comment: Thanks. Python lists are less intuitive than Java 2D arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line creates four list elements which are actually the same list:

```
matrix = [rowMatrix]*4
```

This means modifying `matrix[0][0]` also modifies the other lists.